# -CC option in configure file for MPI install

Tags: mpi, configure

I'm trying to install MPI and set the C Compiler flag with the following:

```
./configure --prefix=MyPath --CC=gcc --CXX=g++ --FC=gfortran
```

Shell tells me

```
configure: error: unrecognized option: `--CC=gcc'
```

When I use

```
./configure --help
```

I see that all these environment variables are, in fact, defined. If I just do

```
./configure --prefix=MyPath
```

What's wrong with the way I'm trying to set the compiler variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are environment variables (e.g. not options) you can pass on the command line

```
./configure --prefix=MyPath CC=gcc CXX=g++ FC=gfortran
```

should do the trick